# Git pull from master instead of branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-checkout

I was working on master, later I made a branch `sessionwork` and at my server side I checkout this branch by following commands

```
git fetch
git checkout -b SessionWork --track origin/SessionWork
```

Now I have merged this branch to master through source tree, Now I want to get pull from master branch not from session branch as these two branches are merged now how can I do this at my server side ?

Comment: if you run `git checkout master` and then `git status` can you provide output of the `git status` call?

Comment: By doing git checkout master It works fine.. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) master:

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have all changes in `master`:

First go to `master` branch using [checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

```
git checkout master
```

Then take pull from `master` branch

```
git pull origin master
```

Then you will **get latest code into your `local` master branch from `remote`**